# Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wrote a function try to sort through a dataframe(df4) and output only the name.
Table is as follows:

```
df4:
name    species age weight
0   Tatiana Snake   98  464
1   Khaled  Giraffe 50  41
2   Alex    Leopard 6   328
3   Jonath  Monkey  45  463
4   Stefan  Bear    100 50
5   Tommy   Panda   26  349
```

```
  def findHeavyAnimals(animals: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    tb=pd.DataFrame()
    list=[]
    for i in range(animals.shape[0]):
        if animals.iloc[i,3]>=100:
            list.append(animals.iloc[i,0])
            tb['name']=list
    return tb
```

But when I ran the function, I got the ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1)

How can the column not be matching if I have a new dataframe(tb) as the container?
What did I do wrong.

The list and Table looks fine. I just want to function to return the value

```
List:
['Tatiana', 'Alex', 'Jonathan', 'Tommy']
```

tb:
name
0   Tatiana
1   Alex
2   Jonathan
3   Tommy

Comment: `df4.query('weight>100')['name']` If you need the list, add the method `.to_list()` to the previous output

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the way you are attempting to append to the dataframe. You're trying to assign a list of a different size to a dataframe column inside the loop - which results in the error.

Here's a corrected version of function along with whole code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample Data
data = {
    'name': ['Tatiana', 'Khaled', 'Alex', 'Jonath', 'Stefan', 'Tommy'],
    'species': ['Snake', 'Giraffe', 'Leopard', 'Monkey', 'Bear', 'Panda'],
    'age': [98, 50, 6, 45, 100, 26],
    'weight': [464, 41, 328, 463, 50, 349]
}
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data)

def findHeavyAnimals(animals: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    This function filters animals from a dataframe based on their weight.
    If the weight is >= 100, the animal's name is added to the resulting dataframe.
    
    Parameters:
    - animals: The input dataframe containing details of animals.
    
    Returns:
    - A dataframe containing names of animals with weight >= 100.
    """
    
    # Use boolean indexing to filter rows where weight is >= 100
    heavy_animals = animals[animals['weight'] >= 100]
    
    # Select only the 'name' column
    result = heavy_animals[['name']]
    
    # Reset the index and adjust column names for desired format
    result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
    result.columns.name = 'tb'
    
    return result

# Testing the function
print(findHeavyAnimals(df4))
```

which results in below - which I hope works for you.

```
tb      name
0     Tatiana
1       Alex
2     Jonath
3      Tommy
```

If you need the result as a list you can modify the return part of the function like below :

```
return result['name'].tolist()
```

which results in

```
['Tatiana', 'Alex', 'Jonath', 'Tommy']
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! The main mistake like you said was adding the list to dataframe within the look. Thank you so much!